# vhdl programming convert a 11 bit to 6 bit

Tags: vhdl, hardware

How i can convert in vhdl programming language xlinix an 11 bit length binary number (10000000000 =1024 in decimal) to a 6 bit binary number (100000=32(decimal) )

Some examples are:

- 1024(decimal) is 32(decimal) in 6 bit
- 512 (decimal) is 16 (decimal)in 6 bit
- and also if the case is 0 (in 11 bits ) to 6 bit is also 0
- 256(in 11 bit) is 8 in 6 bit
- 768 (in 11 bit)is 24 in 6 bit

generally you divide the 11bit number(decimal) with 32 to get a result out of 32 (which is 6 bit number)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are dividing by `2^5`:

```
    ...
    signal x : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0);
    signal y : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

begin

    y <= x(10 downto 5);
```

Comment: it will work with this two cases?- 256(in 11 bit) is 8 in 6 bit 

 - 768 (in 11 bit)is 24 in 6 bit

Comment: Yes. But you should try it if you don't believe me.